# USB stick: medium not found

Tags: usb, mount, flash

Trying to flash a USB with a bootable OS.

`lsblk` does not detect the disk. `ls /dev/disk/by-id/` reveals the disk lives at `/dev/disk/by-id/usb-NAND_USB2DISK-0:0`.

`sudo fdisk /dev/disk/by-id/usb-NAND_USB2DISK-0\:0`

and

`sudo fsck /dev/disk/by-id/usb-NAND_USB2DISK-0\:0`

each fail with: No medium found while trying to open /dev/sda

What concept am I missing?

Comment: Are you certain the USB stick is good? They are not generally known for their long-term viability … 

Comment: The USB appeared to work a day ago, when I flashed it last.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky, solve the problem. -- It is bad that lsblk does not see the drive, but there are things to test before giving up (reboot, other USB ports, remove other USB devices, other computer, other operating system ...).